# How to convert a deep nested object to an observable and then pluck it

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

First of all, is this the best practice in Angular? Is this possible at all?:
I have an JSON object, which contains many children in children and I want to be some of the subsubsubsubchildren to be console.logged.
I tried this with the following code:

```
const observable1 = of(metaDataResponse); //convert object metaDataResponse to Observable
        console.log(observable1.subscribe( x => { .pipe(pluck('METADATA.ALLOWEDCHANNELS'))))};
```

But this appears to not work. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

My object looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUYtL.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They way you use **`pluck`** is wrong. You are use **.pipe** on nothing so **pluck** won't get you anything. Try this way,

```
const observable1 = of(metaDataResponse).pipe(pluck('METADATA.ALLOWEDCHANNELS'))

observable1.subscribe(console.log)
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pluck-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

**NOTEs**: If you are using array, probably you want to use **from** in place of **of**. **from** will emit objects of array one by one. If a particular object is a nested object, to reach out to any property in depth, you can use `pluck('parentprop', 'childprop', .... )`

Comment: I am getting undefined back :/

Comment: Maybe it's because I have the key `METADATA.ALLOWEDCHANNELS` in my subsubsubchild?

Comment: Check I provided a basic example.

Comment: Thank you for the basic example. But in my use case as I've specified in the question I need to pluck the subsubsubchildren. Can you please provide a way to pluck it?

Comment: You may want to provide us the object structure in that case....

Comment: check I updated the answer to reach to last object.....

Comment: I updated answer to deal with array of objects.... check it.